# Customising the user registration form: Django HTML mashup?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-views

I've build a user registration form and what I hope is a correctly working back end registration mechanism (as far as I know this is not working as I need to define the password validation method in the form):

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password_setp = forms.CharField(label = 'Password', widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    password_conf = forms.CharField(label = 'Repeat Password', widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password_setp', 'password_conf',)

    def passwordconf_validation(self):
        cleaned_pw = self.cleaned_data
        if cleaned_pw['password_setp'] != cleaned_pw[password_conf]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("I\'m sorry, your chosen passwords do not match. Please try again.")
        return cleaned_data['password_conf']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['email'].required = True
    self.fields['first_name'].required = True
    self.fields['last_name'].required = True
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class UserRegistrationView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'oauth/user/registration_form.html'
    model = User
    fields = { 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', }

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Get the list of items for this view. This must be an interable, and may
        be a queryset (in which qs-specific behavior will be enabled).
        """
        if self.queryset is not None:
            queryset = self.queryset
            if hasattr(queryset, '_clone'):
                queryset = queryset._clone()
        elif self.model is not None:
            queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(u"'%s' must define 'queryset' or 'model'"
                                       % self.__class__.__name__)
        return queryset

    def user_registration(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                #Create a new user object instance, but avoid saving it until the password is validated:
                new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                #Set the chosen password if password validated:
                new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
                #Save the User object
                new_user.save()
                return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', { 'new_user': new_user })
        else:
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        return render(request, 'oauth/user/registration_form.html', { 'user_form': user_form })
```

I have one issue - that is the password setup and confirm fields aren't rendering (`password_setp`, `password_conf`).

Once this is rendered correct, I would then like to do is customise the following html to accept all the required fields defined in the UserRegistrationForm class:

```
<form class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action=".">
    <div class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Forename">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Surname">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling `'user_registration(request)'` method in CreateView?

`'def passwordconf_validation(self)`'

this should be

```
def clean_passwordconf(self, **kwargs):
```

You can also inherit django builtin UserCreationForm for create user that already have password validation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I'm inheriting this class using `from django.views.generic import CreateView`

Comment: But CreateView don't have any method that name in 'user_registration' So how it will call?.
Check all method of CreateView here https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Comment: Ahhh...ok, that figures...so what view should I be inheriting from?

Comment: Only you need to add form_class =  UserRegistrationForm in CreateView     that will give you 'form' object in template So you can user form object in template for render field or form

Comment: Ok - and which view should I pass in?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313214/usercreationform-show-error-when-fields-are-empty?rq=1      
 https://www.pshrmn.com/tutorials/django/users/